# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree "dependency issue creating a sonar plugin"

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm creating a plugin to add some custom rules. To start, my work is based on: [/sonar-examples/plugins/java-custom-rules](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules). This sample works very well and some rules I have created too.

I have a problem trying to create a rule based on [UnusedPrivateFieldCheck.java version 2.1](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/2.1/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/UnusedPrivateFieldCheck.java).  `sonarRunner` fails with the following message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree

The line that fails is:

```
AstNode identifierAstNode = ((JavaTree) tree).getAstNode().getFirstChild(JavaTokenType.IDENTIFIER);
```

In rule version 2.3 `JavaTree` is not used, but unfortunately
the sonar version 4.3.2 works with version 2.1

Is the `JavaTree` class accessible from plugin classpath sharing? Is there a special configuration? Is something missing at my pom.xml? Must I wait until version 2.3?

Comment: Please detail what you are trying to achieve in another question.I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

`JavaTree` is not part of the `org.sonar.plugins.java.api` and is therefore not accessible from plugin classpath sharing to implement your own rules.

This class is intended for internal uses only.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. I appreciate your support.

I understood that my rules could not use JavaTree or SemanticModel class because they are not part of org.sonar.plugins.java.api.

Do you know why these classes are not available to create custom rules?

Comment: Simply because it is difficult to change a published API and as this is still incomplete and work in progress, it is not something we want to be unable to change later on.